# Laravel does not work without index.php path?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I use Laravel 5.4. At localhost all was working, but in production server it works only with path: `/index.php/controller`.

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you try using: **php artisan serve** to run your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you didn't configure well your virtualhost.

To fix this issue, have a look there : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#web-server-configuration

Comment: You see, it is `Pretty URLs` rules

Comment: going from `/index.php/controller` to `/controller` is url rewriting and thus, it is using pretty url.

Quoted from the link : 
 "to provide URLs without the index.php front controller in the path"

Comment: My public file in directory `/var/www/html` and framework in `/var/www/framework`. So file .htacess is located in html/

Comment: Why did you change the base directory structure of your application ?
public files are supposed to be in `[...]/public/` and your application in `[...]/`

Comment: I made changes(paths) in html/index.php file. It works, but url was not changes

Comment: Have you check your configuration to see if .htaccess file are processed ?

Comment: how to check this?

Comment: Inside your vhost configuration file, it should be an `AllowOverride`directive.

You can also check if the mod_rewrite is enabled, it should appear in the apache modules list via `phpinfo`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP, you can easily define a VirtualHost inside your ***xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf*** file like this:

```
<VirtualHost local.laravel.com:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
ServerName local.laravel.com:80
ErrorLog "logs/local.laravel.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/local.laravel.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you can define the host in your ***C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*** file:

```
127.0.0.1 local.laravel.com
```

Restart Apache in Xampp and try it.